# Images rotated 90/-90 degrees are blurry jquery rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

When using this jquery plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation
and I rotate an image 90 degrees either direction they end up being blurry. If the image is rotated 180 degrees its not blurry.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The pixels (little squares that make up images) are not rotated, just moved around. This is why your image looks grainy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use css transition to rotate image:

```
img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
```

take care

Answer (score 3):

Try using images having `even * even` or `odd * odd` dimensions to set the center of rotation to a pixel corner or to a pixel center.

Here I rotated a 10*7 image (animated gif), you can see that the rotated pixels doesn't really align with the pixel grid of the screen:

[image: rot]

Comment: This helped a little bit but not by much. Thanks though!